# Limit of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, wormholes

Is there any limit to the bending of spacetime due to gravity?
I have been reading about wormholes and how they bend spacetime and connect two systems. But if there is no limit to gravity, we can infinitely bend spacetime and it will form infinitely many wormholes which should not be possible, because we will never know where the first wormhole opened. So, there has to be a limit to gravity.

Comment: You need to define more clearly what you mean by _a limit of gravity_.  For example you could measure the gravitational acceleration if you hover near a black hole and you'd find it goes to infinity as you approach the horizon. In this sense the horizon is the place where gravity becomes infinite. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/647494/1325) for more details. Is this the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: Wormholes are *theoretical* solutions of the GR equations, but we strongly suspect that they're physically impossible, or at best completely unstable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Einstein%E2%80%93Rosen_bridges

Comment: @JohnRennie I am trying to say that gravity cannot be infinity. If gravity is infinity we could fold space time infinitely many times.

Answer (score 1):

General Relativity is a classical theory. That is, not quantum. Given a distribution of matter, you solve the field equations to find how space is curved. If you have a large compact mass, the solution is a black hole. Spacetime is more curved deeper in. At the center, there is a singularity where spacetime is infinitely curved.

This singularity is not real. We know that General Relativity doesn't work on the Planck scale, or distances smaller than $10^{-35}$ meter or so. To get a real solution, we need a quantum theory of gravity. We don't have one. So we don't know what the center is really like. We don't know what limits to curvature there are.